# Navigating through images in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database

Basically I have a page default.aspx that has an image control on it. When the page loads, that image control's url is set to ShowImage.ashx. The image is then populated with an image that is called from the database via the ShowImage handler.

I understand sessions & passing values but, how can we navigate through the images when the user clicks "Next" or "Back"?

I tried to grab the ShowImage session id & subtract 1 for back & add one for next but it isn't working.

How would I go about doing this & is there an easier way to do this. My goal is to make an image website that the user can simply navigate through.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're storing the image id in the session state and fetching it in the handler.

There really is no reason to store anything in the session state in this context and it absolutely should *not* be used to pass a value from place to place - you'll end up creating a very flaky application. You should pass the image id in the URL to the handler (e.g. `ShowImage.ashx?imageId=1`) and then changing the image is simply a case of changing this url.

Comment: Okay thanks that helps. I was making it more complicated than it should be. It's all a matter of decreasing the id and passing it over through the URL. My only other question is if I do that on the default.aspx page, and I decrease the id every time it's clicked how would I get the id number to save after it has been decreased ( because the button will cause a postback)?

Comment: I see what you mean and a good place to store the current id is the ViewState. The ViewState is stored in the form so, unlike the session state, behaves nicely with the forward and back buttons and secondary tabs etc. Alternatively, you could also use a hidden form field on your page to store the id, or you could use the querystring of your `default.aspx` page.

Comment: Thanks so much Tim, view state worked perfect. I appreciate the help!